# Could not load NIB in bundle ! Customs Cell in TableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a problem with my `tableView`. I want have 6 different cell in the `tableView`.

So, in the `viewDidLoad`, i have this:

```
[_tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"KBCategoriePriceTableViewCell" bundle:nil]
 forCellReuseIdentifier:@"KBCategoriePriceTableViewCell"];
```

For other cells, it's the same code and, in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{   
[tableView setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone];
    NSString* nameCell = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    if([nameCell isEqualToString:CELL_VIEW_CATEGORY_PRICE]){
        KBCategoriePriceTableViewCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"KBCategoriePriceTableViewCell"];
        [cell setBackgroundColor:[[receive category] colorBackground]];
        [cell.buttonCategorie setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [cell.buttonCategorie setEnabled:NO];
        [cell.buttonCategorie setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[[receive category] imageName]]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [cell.buttonDevise setTitle:[[receive devise] symbole] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [cell.buttonCategorie setEnabled:NO];
        [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
        return cell;
}
}
```

But when i launch my app, it's crash ! With this error message :

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </Users/jean-nicolasdefosse/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.1/Applications/20031DF6-D297-44D0-9D67-4AD3439D85F7/KillTheBill.app> (loaded)' with name 'KBCategoriePriceTableViewCell''
```

I don't understand why it doesn't work.

I remove reference and add the files in the project, i check the target and the custom cell `KBCategoriePriceTableViewCell` have as identifier in "xib": `KBCategoriePriceTableViewCell`.

Please help me !

Comment: you need to create prototype call rather than nib file

Comment: you need to change to storyboard and do it all in storyboard -- it will save you an incredible amount of time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error message is saying that you do not have a file named `KBCategoriePriceTableViewCell.nib` in your project.

Also you should always return a cell in the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.

Comment: Thank for the anwser. I check the name of the xib and it wasn't the same of the .m and the .h

Answer (score 0):

You need to load Custom cell like below code..

You need to check for nil condition also as initially we need not have any custom cell to load..

```
static NSString *cellidentifier=@"cell";
    KBCategoriePriceTableViewCell *cell=(KBCategoriePriceTableViewCell *)[explortableview dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellidentifier];
    if (cell==nil)
    {
        [[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"KBCategoriePriceTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell=self.categoriesCell; //categoriesCell is reference of KBCategoriePriceTableViewCell in which you connected at xib

    }
```

Hope it helps you..!

Comment: No you can also register a cell (NIB or Class) with tableView and just dequeue it.

Answer (score 0):

Don't load the Nib file in `viewDidLoad`.

You can use the code below:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
        static NSString *cellidentifier=@"KBCategoriePriceTableViewCell";
        KBCategoriePriceTableViewCell *cell=(KBCategoriePriceTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellidentifier];
        if(cell==nil){
            NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"KBCategoriePriceTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
            cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
        }
        cell.lbl_name.text=@"Meeting";
        return cell;

}
```

Here, the   `cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];` is the first cell like that you can load the dynamic cells.

Comment: Why not? It is the preferred way in iOS 7, the table view will be able to optimize the loading.

Comment: If you going to load dynamic cell means this is the better approach.

Comment: No it is not, it is just different way of doing it. It is not better nor worse, but in iOS 7 the prefered way is to register the cell and dequeue it with [`dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006943-CH3-SW92)

Answer (score 0):

Careful not to invoke a prototype cell using initWithXib because that will crash